# Sed command: search for a string & replace 1 character after the string

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to use the `sed` command in a shell script in osx/bash. I am well able to replace some content of `MyFile` using the simplest form of command like below

`sed -i -e 's/abc/123/g' MyFile`

where MyFile content is `xyzabcdefghijk`. The above command works great to replace `abc` with `123` & makes the output as `xyz123defghijk`

But, How do I modify the `sed` command to replace `2` characters after `abc` as well along with `abc`. In clear words, **I want to search for a string `abc` in `MyFile` & replace `abc + 2` characters after it with `12345`.**

So, if `MyFile` contains, `abcdefghijk` then the output should contain `xyz12345fghijk`

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change `abc` and the two characters after `abc`:

```
$ sed -e 's/abc../12345/g' MyFile
xyz12345fghijk
```

In regular expressions, `.` matches any single character.  So, `..` matches two characters and `abc..` matches `abc` and any two characters after `abc`.

To make the change to the file in-place:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/abc../12345/g' MyFile
```

Comment: if I want to replace between 2 characters like "abc" by "123", what is the `sed` option. You mind answering this small question..

Comment: The between-two-characters part is not clear to me.  Would you clarify what you mean by that?  Maybe, add sample input and output.

Comment: lets say sample input is `xyz"123"45fghijk`. I need the output to be xyz"96701"45fghijk...... So after `xyz`, there are 2 double quotes occurring. I just want to replace the string between the 2 double-qoutes occuring right after `abc`, with something like `96701`

Comment: I hope I made my question clear :) I am new to this & trying to do some scratchy stuff :)

Comment: Man !! you are a genius. Thanks a lot.